# loop to read datagridview columns, even non-visible ones

Tags: c#, datagridview, visible

Hello I've got a snippet of code here where I'm looping through the columns of each row in my datagridview. I'm simply exporting a CSV type file out. This code is writing to that file.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile))
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < runGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (int j = 0; j < runGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
       {
          if (runGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
          {
               sb.Append(runGrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + ",");
          }
          else
          {
          sb.Append(",");
          }
        }
     sw.WriteLine(sb);
      }
    sw.Close();
 }
```

Problem with this being is my first column is a non-visible one (just an index actually) and there will be few other non-visible ones to come. When I loop through `runGrid.Columns.Count` it doesn't include the non-visible columns. Is there a way to to include them? Besides making all the columns visible, running this code, then making those individuals back to `visible = false`?

Comment: Perhaps you removed this column from columns collection somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with hidden columns, I've tested it to be sure. Something else is wrong.

Note: StringBuilder should be instantiated before row loop, and cleared before column loop

```
sb.Clear()
```

Comment: good call. and yes, it looks like the read/load function wasn't reading in enough columns. got it fixed though, thanks.